# How do print the odd letters of an input in python

Tags: python

I have to do this for school, but I can't work it out. I have to get an input and print ONLY the odd characters. So far I've put the input in a list and I have a while loop (which was a clue on the task sheet), but I can't work it out. Please help:

```
inp = input('What is your name? ')
name = []
name.append(inp)
n=1

while n<len(name):
```

Comment: I know it may not seem like the same thing but take a look at that question. It's useful because the OP does the "modulo trick" (`%2`), which is one common way to do this, and the accepted answer uses slicing, which can be used on strings as well as lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print inp[1::2]
```

I guess thats all you need

Comment: You could have voted for the dupe target where that's the accepted answer :P

Comment: Wow -- you win this round of python golf

Comment: fixed ... and I also voted(or hammered:P ) to close as dupe ...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put the string in a list, a string is already essentially a list of characters (more formally, it is a "sequence").

You can use indexing and the modulus operator (`%`) for this

```
inp = input('What is your name? ')
n = 0   # index variable

while n < len(inp):
    if n % 2 == 1:      # check if it is an odd letter
        print(inp[n])   # print out that letter
    n += 1
```

Comment: great answer :) and much more educational than mine +1

Comment: fwiw I would have done what you did had it not been a request for hw help :)